# Linked-list is confusing

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

I am stuck, as I don't understand what is this code doing:

```
struct node
{
    int info;          /* This is the value or the data 
                          in the node, as I understand */
    struct node *next; /* This looks like a pointer. But 
                          what is it doing in real life? */
} *last;               /* What is this and why is it 
                          outside the body? What is this 
                          thing doing? */
```

I know that when a node is created, it has a value, and it is pointing to some other node
but I don't understand the syntax.

Is this a better way of writing the code above?

Is there a simpler way of writing the same struct for better understanding?

In my lectures they presume that the student has understanding of what they teach.

Comment: Thanks I will be more pressie in future

Answer (score 1):

Well, we can explain this to you, but we can't *understand* it for you.

Code snippet you've provided is definition of variable `last`, being pointer to newly defined structure type `node`. It can be written other way as:

```
typedef struct _node_t {
    int info;
    node_t *next;
} node_t;

node_t *last;
```

This way we define `typedef`, which is, say, alias of type definition to some short name — in this particular case, it aliases structure of two fields as the name `node_t`. Wherever you define something as being of type `node_t`, you tell compiler that you mean *'this should be aforementioned structure of two fields'*, and `node_t *last` means *'variable `last` should be pointer to `node_t` type'*.

So, back to syntax:

```
struct foo {
    int a;
    float b;
    void *c;
} bar, *baz;
```

means *'Define structure type `foo`, and make it contain three fields — integer `a`, float-point `b` and untyped pointer `c`, then make variable `bar` to be of this structure type, and make variable `baz` to point to this structure type'*.

Now to pointer. What you see is called 'recursive definition', e.g. type mentions itself in it's own definition. They are okay, if language supports them (C does), but one could avoid recursive definitions in linked list node structure by specifying next node pointer to be just untyped:

```
struct node_t {
    int info;
    void *next;
};
```

This way you no longer reference `node_t` type from `node_t` type, but that adds you some inconveniences when using this type (you have to explicitly cast `next` to `node_t` type, like `((*node_t)(last->next))->info` instead of just `last->next->info`).

If you feel you need additional reference, consider taking a look at interactive online tutorials, like http://www.learn-c.org/ (I'm not affiliated).

Comment: That is very confusing nomenclature.

Comment: I'm personally again `typedef`-ing pointers without the name indicating that it's a pointer (e.g. `nodePtr`) as this usually leads to unclear code - `node last` doesn't look like a pointer.

Comment: I'm personally against naming types without indicating it as type, so if I'd write this structure by my own, I'd name it `node_t`, and not make it pointer at all, forcing programmer to explicitly use asterisks wherenever pointer is needed.

Comment: Then why did you write the example like that? The OP had explicit asterisks.

Comment: @ahmed, don't hesitate to accept an answer if it helped you to solve your issue.

Comment: I have got some clue, but as this is a new set of codes which needs some more understanding (what is relay going inside the compiler) at this stage of learning such problem always exists.As I can not see what is going on , so merely reading the codes and thinking makes me blank. I think If i rewrite this code many times which I am doing and start using it I may be clear. Your suggestions were helpful thanks

Comment: I think i should post the complete code of program with my questions.it is not an assignment :) my classes for 3rd semester have not yet started , I have a wish to learn and the online lectures are not helping me , may be my understanding level is not good.

Comment: @modchan Inside the struct definition, you should refer to the struct as `struct node_t` instead of `node_t` since the `typedef` has not been done at that point

Comment: @ahmed I recommend http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ by Zed A Shaw. Work through the exercises patiently. I learned a lot from that book

Comment: i will get this book as learning lists at this stage of edu will save me from lot of trouble at later stages thanks

Answer (score 0):

that is the simplest way to write a linked list node , but why name it `last` ? name it `node` instead , this makes it more understandable , but here's how it works.

when a linked list is first created it contains only the root node (the first node in a linked list) , when you add a node , you fill the `info` field with the data that node will hold  (note that `info` may be any kind of data , character , string , int ...) then set `next` to `NULL` , since that node is the last node in the list.
 when you add another node , you change the value of `next` to point to the node you just added and you set the value of `next` to `NULL` in the node you just created because now that is the last node in the list .
you can repeat this to add as many nodes as your memory allow you to.
[this link](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson7.html) may help you to better understand structures

Comment: Now I can see the picture which is not blur, I appreciate your generosity thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef struct marks {
    int m;
    struct marks *next;
} marks_t;
```

This way we define a structure so that a Linked List can be formed. Now we have defined the last variable next as a "structure pointer" which gives us the address of the next element in the list (i.e. as structure only)!

The last element does not point to any node (here marks structure) and hence the pointer variable has NULL value.

Now to define the first element:

```
marks_t *list;

if (list == NULL) {
    list = (marks_t *) malloc(sizeof(marks_t));
}

list->m = 15;
list->next = NULL;
```

Now if we want to add an element next to this (i.e. second element):

```
marks_t *next1;

next1 = (marks_t *) malloc(sizeof(marks_t));
next1->m = 27;
next1->next = NULL;
list->next = next1; // Storing address of next1 structure in list
```

Comment: I've fixed a typo in your code, you assign `new1` to `list->next`, but your variable is called `next1`.

Comment: blue I am new in this subject and syntax dances in front of my eyes.

Comment: can you please post a simpler syntax which I may understand :)

Comment: ahmed: I too found it very confusing at first. What i did was understand the basics of Linked List first.